# Duplicate C# web service proxy classes generated for Java types

Tags: c#, java, web-services

My question is about integration between a Java web service and a C# .NET client.

Service: CXF 2.2.3 with Aegis databinding
Client: C#, .NET 3.5 SP1

For some reason Visual Studio generates two C# proxy enums for each Java enum. The generated C# classes do not compile.

For example, this Java enum:

```
public enum SqlDialect {
    GENERIC, SYBASE, SQL_SERVER, ORACLE;
}
```

Produces this WSDL:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="SqlDialect">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="GENERIC" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="SYBASE" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="SQL_SERVER" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="ORACLE" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

For this WSDL Visual Studio generates two partial C# classes (generated comments removed):

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="SqlDialect", Namespace="http://somenamespace")]
public enum SqlDialect : int {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    GENERIC = 0,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    SYBASE = 1,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    SQL_SERVER = 2,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    ORACLE = 3,
}


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3082")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://somenamespace")]
public enum SqlDialect {
    GENERIC,
    SYBASE,
    SQL_SERVER,
    ORACLE,
}
```

The resulting C# code does not compile:

```
The namespace 'somenamespace' already contains a definition for 'SqlDialect'
```

I will appreciate any ideas...

Comment: how are you consuming the wsdl in visual studio? add service reference? add web reference? is this visual studio 08 (i assume)?  have you tried consuming the service manually using the command line?

Comment: Sorry for missing details - I'm using Visual Studio 2008, adding a Service Reference, and have also tried using svcutils.exe with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I found what "makes" Visual Studio generate duplicate proxy classes... Our web service data model is polymorphic and uses abstract classes - this is essentially why we use Aegis databinding. **If there is more than one abstract class in the hierarchy, Visual Studio will generate duplicate proxies.**

For example, in this web service contract:

```
AbstractRestrictionDef getRestriction(...parameters...)
```

these classes would not work:

```
abstract class AbstractModelObject -– abstract class AbstractRestrictionDef –- class SqlRestrictionDef
```

but these classes would:

```
abstract class AbstractModelObject -– class AbstractRestrictionDef -– class ParsedRestrictionDef
```

Answer (score 0):

For certain WSDLs, I have had extra code generated (in my case, extra class members that didn't exist).  This caused problems when trying to use it, so I just deleted the code I identified as excess and it started working.  I'd try deleting one of the enums and seeing what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I also edited the code manually, and deleting the first of the enum classes resolved the compilation issues.

However, errors in the generated code are just a sign of bigger troubles. For example:
- the C# client cannot correctly un-marshall Java exceptions - any server-side exception information is lost;
- null values are un-marshalled not as C# nulls, but as XmlNode objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the service referance as a .net 2 referance; use add service referance > advanced > add web reference...

Answer (score 0):

You could also try alternative proxy generator http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/ , which seems to handle this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think to add this WSDL using visual studio 2008, it should support SOAP 1.1 , check the version of this SOAP using [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/installing-on-windows.html) application or similar apps.